# problem get products with retrofit (Woocommerce site)

Tags: android, kotlin, woocommerce, retrofit, getmethod

I want to get all products from site `woocommer` but getting an error of 401 whenever I login with app and get token. My code snippet is mentioned below

`class retrofit`

```
class ApiClient {
companion object {
    val BASE_URL = "https://refahshahrvand.com/wp-json/"
    private var retrofit:Retrofit? = null
    private var client:OkHttpClient? = null

    fun getClient() : Retrofit {
        client= OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(100,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(100,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        }

        return retrofit!!
    }

  }
}
```

class apiInterface

```
   interface ApiInterface {

                @POST("wc/v3/products")
                @FormUrlEncoded
                fun getNamePro ( @Header("token") token: String,@Field("consumer_key") consumer_key: 
                  String,@Field("consumer_secret") consumer_secret: String):  Call<List<AllProducts>>
             }
```

this call get method

```
  private fun AllProductList(){
    var token2: String
    res = Respon()
    autologin = Autologin(context)
    token2 = autologin?.getToken().toString()

    val apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface::class.java)
    val call : Call<List<AllProducts>> = apiInterface.getNamePro(token2, res?.consumer_key.toString(), res?.consumer_Secret.toString() )

    call.enqueue(
            object : Callback<List<AllProducts>> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<AllProducts>>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.e("*****-onFailure-*****" + t.toString(), call.toString())
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<AllProducts>>, response: Response<List<AllProducts>>) {
                    val pr = response.body()


                    if (response != null) {
                        //adding items in list
                        for (i in 0..9) {
                            list_Prod.add(pr?.get(i)?.getName().toString())
                        }
                        mRecyclerView = view?.findViewById(R.id.Prod_recycler_view)
                        var mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view?.context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) as LinearLayoutManager

                        mRecyclerView!!.layoutManager = mLayoutManager
                        mAdapter = ProductsAdapter(list_Prod)
                        mRecyclerView!!.adapter = mAdapter

                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            Login.STATE_LOGIN = true
                            Log.e("*****-isSuccessful-****" + pr?.get(1)?.getName().toString(), response.toString())

                            for(i in 0..list_Prod!!.size -1){

                                Toast.makeText(context , pr?.get(i)?.getName().toString(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                // Log.e("** User_display_name : " + pr?.get(i)?.getName().toString(), response.toString())
                            }

                        } else {
                            Log.e("********#error#*******" + pr.toString(), call.toString())
                        }

                    }
                }

            })
}
```

Error logcat. Please help me.

```
>E/********#error#*******null: retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@308939e

>E/----------response---------: Response{protocol=h2, code=401, message=,  url=https://refahshahrvand.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be following -

1. Since you are getting HTTP error code 401, i.e unauthorized that means token is not valid and mismatch in API endpoints
2. Key mismatch in a model class and the response

Comment: user login and save token , so send token , cunsomer key and consumer secret value to url HTTPS ,